# How to restart my Heroku Django app at the command line?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I deleted my app from Heroku web and now I want to recreate again but it says that it keeps the old name. I want to do:

```
heroku create globalnewstt
```

but it says:

> No such app as peaceful-taiga-6373

(The last name and I deleted that repo from Heroku web)
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you get as the result from this command?: `git remote -v`

Answer (score 1):

You have your old Heroku app in your `.git/config` file. To fix this, run the command:

```
$ git remote rm heroku
```

Then, create your app fresh using `heroku create` =)